# Null Return in SQL Function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL function that is putting a NULL value in the variable because there is no corresponding record in the table it's getting the csv.string_val.

```
create function dbo.MyFunctionName (@ticket_id int)
  returns nvarchar(max)
  as
  BEGIN

  declare @assignees nvarchar(max)
  set @assignees = ''
  select @assignees = @assignees + '; ' +  csv.string_val
  from database.incident_table cr join assignment_table asg
on asg.item_id = cr.id
join user_table au on asg.app_user_id = au.app_user_id
join user_link_table aupl on aupl.app_user_id = au.app_user_id
join system_value_table csv on csv.owner_id = aupl.user_prof_id
left join system_config_table cs on cs.cfg_setting_id = csv.cfg_setting_id
where asg.item_defn_id = 648
and cs.cfg_setting_const = 'username'
and csv.cfg_setting_owner_type_name = 'USER_PROFILE'
and asg.item_id = @ticket_id

if len(@assignees) >= 3 set @assignees = right(@assignees, len(@assignees) - 2)

return @assignees
END
```

The problem is when there is no record for the ticket number in the assignment_table, the @assignees variable is null and I get "Invalid parameter passed to the RIGHT function."

I'm obviously having a brain cramp because I can't figure out how to get it to NOT execute the RIGHT() function if the @assignees parameter is null. I'm sure the answer is simple but it's escaping me at the moment.

Edit: Using the STUFF and FOR XML fixed it for me.

Comment: Either perform another if before that one, or use the isnull function to check.

Comment: Depends on what you want to have happen when assignees is null.

Comment: This code runs **without error** here: `declare @assignees nvarchar(max) = null; if len(@assignees) >= 3 set @assignees = right(@assignees, len(@assignees) - 2)`, so is there perhaps more code that we are not seeing?

Comment: What is the aim of this function? It looks like it's to create a delimited list using a semicolon. Would it not be a better idea to make use of `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH`?

Comment: Not only use STUFF and FOR XML but make this an inline table valued function instead of a scalar one.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. The STUFF and FOR XML solved my problem. It works like a charm now.